# simplest way to integrate dynamic content into statically served page on Node.JS via Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dynamic-content

I am serving a static webpage from Node.JS via Express webserver:

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
```

What is the most minimalistic way to integrate some dynamic content, e.g. a list of items that is retrieved from a database into such a page?
I see the possibility to "fake" a .js file on the server that is actually dynamically created and then loaded in an `index.html` that resides inside the `public` folder on the server:

```
app.get('/myScript.js', (req, res) => {
  data = getDataFromDatabase();
  res.send('var data1 = ' + data[0] + '; var data2 = ' + data[1]);
});
```

This seems extremely hacky and I wonder what the best minimalistic approach to this is.

Comment: Given that you are asking its a reasonable approach. If the data doesn't change all that often or is under your control you could even write the the file when the data changes and it wouldn't need to be dynamic at all. However one thing to consider is returning the data as JSON will help keep you from having to deal with various text escaping issues.

Comment: If I understood you right, you basically want to retrieve data and render that data into your main page? If that's the case, why not use a view engine like ejs?

Comment: @n0m4d I was looking for a minimal solution without view engines but see that this might indeed be the way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return a response from a callback inside of your get route. I do something like this:

Endpoint:

```
router.get('/people', (req, res) => {
    People.list((error, response) => {
        if (error) return res.end();
        return res.send(response);
    });
});
```

Model:

```
module.exports = {
    connect: (callback) => {
        r.connect({
            host: config.db.host,
            port: config.db.port,
            db: config.db.name
        })
        .then((connection) => {
            return callback(null, connection);
        })
        .error((err) => {
            return callback(err);
        });
    },
    list: function (callback) {
        this.connect((err, connection) => {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            r.db(config.db.name).table(config.db.tables.people)
            .run(connection)
            .then((cursor) => {
                return cursor.toArray();
            })
            .then((users) => {
                return callback(null, users);
            })
            .error((err) => {
                return callback(err);
            });
        });
    },
    ...
```

With this then I get the response object printed to my screen. The model code is rethinkdb code, but you can substitute that with whatever you are using. Sorry if this wasn't quite what you were after. Best of luck with your build =)

Comment: I do not see that this is significantly different from the example in my question. The primary difference is that you are passing the `res.send` from a callback.

Comment: You're right. I was just showing another way to handle this with a callback to get back your response object.